# How to open a MS Access database that someone has sent me

Tags: ms-access

I've been sent via dropbox a MS Access database, so I've downloaded it and saved it.

It seems to open-up just fine but if I try to open any of the forms is says it's an invalid path and it looks like: c:\users\xxx_xxxx\dropbox\database.mdb is not a valid path. The xxx_xxxx there is the name of the person who sent it and it's not a path on my computer. But I'm opening the database.mdb file which he sent me, so how come it references this other path. Why not c:\my computer\etc etc? How do I change it?

thanks

Comment: I suspect they have failed to send you the back end and that you have linked tables. Go to External data --> Linked Table Manager

Comment: humm... what they've sent is about eight mdb files with similar names. To me they looked just like different versions of the same thing. If I open the biggest file I can see all the tables and forms down the panel on the left, but double clicking causes the invalid path error. If I open one of the smaller files I can only see the tables on the left panel, no forms, no queries. But I can open the tables and see all the info. What am I doing wrong, haven't used MS Access for years

Comment: @remou could it be I just need to update a path somewhere that I'm too clueless to find?

Comment: Go to External data --> Linked Table Manager are there any tables listed?

Comment: @remou yeah the five tables are listed but the path beside them points to somewhere not on my computer. I tried pointing it to the file I opened (the biggest one I mentioned before) but it gives the error: The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query...

Comment: There should be a clue. The structure is path & database name, look for a matching database name.

Comment: OK so I need to update the path, but it doesn't let me. I get that error: The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query...

Comment: If there is an error, you have selected the wrong mdb / accdb. Look for the mdb / accdb that does contain that table.

Comment: Thanks friend, got it sorted now. Never used MS Access much before, bit confused. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

If your Access version is >= 2007, open the Linked Table Manager from the Database Tools section of the ribbon.

[image: Linked Table Manager is found on Database Tools section of the ribbon]

In earlier Access versions, I think the Linked Table Manager was a menu item under the Database Tools submenu.  Hopefully you will find it easily.

In this next screen capture, I've high-lighted one linked table.

[image: Linked tables display in Linked Table Manager]

The source table for that link is in a database file named "C:\share\Access\BigDb_secure.mdb".  If I had re-named that db file or moved it to a different location, I could check the box next to that link, and place another check in the box down at the bottom, "*Always prompt for new location*", then click OK.  Access would next allow me to browse to the proper db file and then use that for the link.

So place check marks next to the links which use a particular db file, and then show the Linked Table Manager the current location of that db file.